# Two strings the have same pointer address

Tags: go, interface

Why is this so? Here's my code:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"        

    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type UserLogin struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}

func Login() {
    row := sql.QueryRow("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=?", "golang")

    userLoginKeys := structs.Names(UserLogin{})
    keys := make([]interface{}, len(userLoginKeys), len(userLoginKeys))
    for i, val := range userLoginKeys {
        keys[i] = &val
        fmt.Println(val)
    }

    fmt.Println(keys)

    _ := row.Scan(keys...)
    v1 := reflect.ValueOf(keys[0]).Elem().String()
    v2 := reflect.ValueOf(keys[1]).Elem().String()
    fmt.Println(v1)
    fmt.Println(v2)
}
```

It prints

```
Username
Password
[0xc4201ca2c0 0xc4201ca2c0] 
$2a$10$F6hR0scvtbFDx0l1GR.OX.ZweozUzwKVTG3H8GBQxpYCEdFifDrzy
$2a$10$F6hR0scvtbFDx0l1GR.OX.ZweozUzwKVTG3H8GBQxpYCEdFifDrzy
```

As you can see, `keys` contains the same address to two different strings. As a result, their values are the same.

My goal is to map `username` and `password` to `UserLogin` struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `keys[i] = &val` to `keys[i] = &userLoginKeys[i]`, so you can get different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, val := range userLoginKeys {
    keys[i] = &val
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

here, val is an independent variable whose address you are assigning to keys[i]. So both time you are getting same address.

Try this:

```
for i:=0; i<len(userLoginKeys); i++ {
    keys[i] = &userLoginKeys[i]
    fmt.Println(keys[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `keys[i] = &val` in your loop, this is assigning the same address to each array element. This also means that you are only getting the last value. What you probably want is `keys[i] = val` (and set the map to use strings instead of *strings).

Comment: So that's just how it works and there's no workaround? `val` only does not work with `Scan()`, it needs `pointers`.

Comment: I guess you don't need to initial the keys array. Just pass it as it is after you declare them.